# what does this symboles means Unm, Uni?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I found in some documents that the creepage and the clearance distance for PCB are calculated according to the value of the tensions Unm and Uni. What does this symboles means ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/89313e3083c4bb4cf7ecd1a6.html). Google is your friend.

There is also this [International standard](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebstore.iec.ch%2Fpreview%2Finfo_iec62497-1%257Bed1.1%257Db.pdf&ei=76k4VZyfKs_6aMSvgKgO&usg=AFQjCNFJq6ijN3X80kUQ3PK6B-_0TrcqPQ&bvm=bv.91427555,d.d2s) that defines them.